# localStorage - object HTMLTableRowElement

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando salvar as alterações do código html da minha página feita por uma interação de javaScript. Mais precisamente quero que a tabela que crio com js mantenha salva as alterações em html.

`localStorage.setItem("resposta", document.querySelector("#tabela-anagrama"));`

```
localStorage.getItem("resposta")
```

Quando eu faço um console.log para ver o que está gravado no localStorage a resposta é [object HTMLTableRowElement]

Minha dúvida é a seguinte como eu faço para gravar o código html e fazer com que quando eu atualize a página a tabela volte já com as alterações gravadas?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o atributo `outerHTML`. Ela irá retornar o código *HTML* do elemento.

```
localStorage.setItem("resposta", document.querySelector("#tabela-anagrama").outerHTML);
```

**Desvantagem:**

Isso tem uma desvantagem, caso você queira adicionar muitos dados, o método `setItem` irá retornar uma `Exception` devido a falta de espaço.

Segue uma tabela com o tamanho disponível, por navegador, para o `Local Storage`:

[image: Capacidade detalhada para vários browsers.]

Comment: Dependendo do conteúdo as vezes o `localStoage` não salve corretamente o conteúdo por que parece convertelo para String, e se mandar como **base64** `localStorage.setItem("resposta",btoa(document.querySelector("#tabela-anagrama").outerHTML));` depois pra recuperar bastaria: `atob(localStorage.resposta);`?

Comment: @RpgBoss O problema que o `base64` quase sempre é maior que o código em si e também ele é uma `String`. Fiz um teste com a tabela a acima, e não ocorreu erros. Mas adicionei a desvantagem do limite de armazenamento (acredito que ele não vá ter erros causa disso).

Comment: Realmente faz bastante sentido, então no fim acho que nem compensa salvar o conteudo HTML, somente os valores e conteúdo, não sei o que acontece se houver muitas quebras de linha.